# DISM RestoreHealth Source

Tags: windows-8, windows-update, file-corruption, windows-8.1-upgrade, dism

I am trying to fix component store corruption on my windows 8 laptop which is preventing me from upgrading to Windows 8.1. I have tried to run DISM /online/Cleanup-image/RestoreHealth but it doesn't work because of an invalid source. My laptop came with the OEM version of windows so I don't have a installation CD. So where or how do I get a valid source to repair my corruption? Can I capture an image from a running Windows 8.1 computer that isn't corrupt? I've read the DISM articles about how do capture and image, but where should I capture a valid image from.

Here are the links to the DISM and CBS logs:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxX6CIDigV64cHEtZWxGRlNaTkE/edit?usp=sharing

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxX6CIDigV64aFJPN1ktamNyekU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: upload the DISM and CBS log files.

Comment: Do you mind if I use Google Drive?

Comment: You might be able to get a clean install iso http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-8/create-reset-refresh-media

Comment: Thanks for the info. Have a couple of other computers this will be helpful for. On my laptop I just did a factory reset and updated from scratch. I was able to install 8.1 then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Decided to just factory reset the computer and run updates from scratch. I was able to install the 8.1 update after this.

Answer (score 1):

The DISM logs showed that the DISM commands have worked:

Summary:
Operation: Detect and Repair 
Operation result: 0x0
Last Successful Step: Entire operation completes.
Total Detected Corruption: 0
CBS Manifest Corruption: 0
CBS Metadata Corruption: 0
CSI Manifest Corruption: 0
CSI Metadata Corruption: 0
CSI Payload Corruption: 0
Total Repaired Corruption: 0
CBS Manifest Repaired: 0
CSI Manifest Repaired: 0
CSI Payload Repaired: 0
CSI Store Metadata refreshed: True

In [this thread](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-windows_install/windows-81-error-code-0xc190010b/984cc428-db86-4910-be20-9a105c365095) on the Microsoft Community forums, some users have used a [Clean Boot](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/929135) in order to upgrade when this error message has presented itself. Another one found that the folder c:\$Windows~BT folder needed to be deleted for the upgrade to finish successfully.

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 0):

Those logs show that there is some meta data corruption that looks to be unrepairable.  That may or may not be a serious problem.  Why does it block you from upgrading to 8.1?  Are you unable to install the pre-req update?  If so can you attempt it again and upload the CBS.log from that attempt?

Comment: Yes I have ensured I have the pre-req updates. I tried updating again. Before I started the update I ran wsreset.exe and made sure I had all peripherals unplugged. This time it errored out with a different code: 0Xc190010b. Here is the link to the CBS log after the update was attempted:https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxX6CIDigV64QnZMNWhscFZjLVE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Where are you seeing the error, because there was no attempt made to install anything in that cbs.log, and there were no errors indicated?

Comment: In the Windows Store while 8.1 is downloading/installing it gets all of the way to the "Preparing to Restart Stage" and then says "This app wasn't installed." And when I view the details it says "Something happened and the Windows 8.1 couldn't be installed. Please try again. Error code: 0xc190010b". I can't think of much else besides a clean install.

Comment: Have you been able to find anything in the log that stands out?